# Enable Disable radio buttons with buttons & Google's CSS won't format "action" button

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script

I'm just trying out the code to see how it works.

I created two buttons, formatted with Google's CSS package, and one button enables the radios and the other disables them.

There are two issues I can't solve.
1. The code won't disable the radios.
2. The format for the first button, class="action", isn't blue.  It is all gray and turns blue only when I select it.  Then it's gray again when un-selected.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

<div>    
<button class="action" onclick="enable()" >Enable</button>
<button onclick="disable()">Disable</button>
</div>

<div>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="1">
<lable for="1">First</lable>

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="2">
<lable for="2">Second</lable>
</div>

<script>
function disable(){ 
          document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("2").disabled = true;
       }

function enable(){
          document.getElementById("1").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("2").disabled = false;
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.  The issue was the revision level of chrome.  Once I loaded the latest, Chrome version, the code worked as expected.